# Fetch API with token returns "Bad request" but works with curl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a fetch POST that returns a Token, which I then need to use for a fetch GET to extract the data I need. The GET with token works in CURL via:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://myCorp.csod.com/services/api/Recruiting/JobRequisitionDetails/Ad\
  - H 'Authorization: Bearer myToken' \
  - H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

I want to do similar with JavaScript. I have the following code to POST (to get the token) and then use it (`data.access_token`) in a GET

```
fetch(proxyUrl + 'https://myCorp.csod.com/services/api/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    let headers = {
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
    fetch(
        proxyUrl + "https://myCorp.csod.com/services/api/Recruiting/JobRequisitionDetails/Ad",
        {    
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + data.access_token,
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            }
        }
    )
      .then((response) =>console.log(response))
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
});
```

"ProxyUrl" in this case is a proxy for CORS. It will print out "undefined" and in the console it will log "bad request"

[image]

I assume something in my code is wrong, anyone that can help?

Comment: What is `proxyUrl`?

Comment: Why you are using `proxyUrl` inside fetch? It is not required

Comment: Maybe it was unclear, I have updated the post. ProxyUrl is a proxy for CORS.